# jQuery image swap if else

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write a basic image swap with javascript/jquery.

For some reason, my if/else statements aren't running correctly. Am I using this incorrectly?

Thanks

Javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var images = new Array();
        var comic = document.getElementById("comicssubsite").src;
        var artwork = document.getElementById("artworksubsite").src;
        var about = document.getElementById("aboutsubsite").src;

        images[0] = "./images/SiteDesign/Comics_subsites_hover.png";
        images[1] = "./images/SiteDesign/Comics_subsites.png";

        images[2] = "./images/SiteDesign/Artwork_subsites_hover.png";
        images[3] = "./images/SiteDesign/Artwork_subsites.png";

        images[4] = "./images/SiteDesign/About_subsites_hover.png";
        images[5] = "./images/SiteDesign/About_subsites.png";

        function onHover() {
            if (comic) {
            $("#comicssubsite").attr('src', images[0]);
            }
            else if (artwork) {
            $("#artworksubsite").attr('src', images[2]);
            }
            else if (about) {
            $("#aboutsubsite").attr('src', images[4]);
            }
        }
        function offHover() {
            if (comic) {
            $("#comicssubsite").attr('src', images[1]);
            }
            else if (artwork) {
            $("#artworksubsite").attr('src', images[3]);
            }
            else if (about)
            $("#aboutsubsite").attr('src', images[5]);
            }
        }

    </script>
```

HTML (snippet)

```
            <div class="span2">
                <div id="pages">
                    <span class="pageitems" ><a href="./?action=homepage&page=1&site=comics"><img id="comicssubsite" src="./images/SiteDesign/Comics_subsites.png" alt="comics bg" onmouseover="onHover();" onmouseout="offHover();"/></a></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span2">
                <div id="pages">
                    <span class="pageitems"><a href="./?action=homepage&page=1&site=artwork"><img id="artworksubsite" src="./images/SiteDesign/Artwork_subsites.png" alt="artwork bg" onmouseover="onHover();" onmouseout="offHover();"/></a></span>    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span2">
                <div id="pages">
                    <span class="pageitems"><a href="./?action=homepage&page=1"><img id="aboutsubsite" src="./images/SiteDesign/About_subsites.png" alt="about bg" onmouseover="onHover();" onmouseout="offHover();"/></a></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery, you should use it for the `hover` events as well, e.g. `$('img#comicssubsite').hover();`

Comment: You're missing a brace on your last `else if`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your if-statements check for the `src` attribute of the respective element to be not empty. That is not really what you want - they always will be executed. Also, you should use jQuery everywhere if you have decided to use it, especially on DOM things like event handling.

Your use of an array as a data structure is a good start, yet quite useless as you still address the items manually instead of programmatically. Use an object [literal] as a key-value-map to get the urls by the image id:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var images = {
        "comicssubsite": [
            "./images/SiteDesign/Comics_subsites_hover.png",
            "./images/SiteDesign/Comics_subsites.png"
        ],
        "artworksubsite": [
            "./images/SiteDesign/Artwork_subsites_hover.png",
            "./images/SiteDesign/Artwork_subsites.png"
        ],
        "aboutsubsite": [
            "./images/SiteDesign/About_subsites_hover.png",
            "./images/SiteDesign/About_subsites.png"
        ]
    };
    function mouseover(e) {
        if (this.id in images) // check for key in map
            this.src = images[this.id][0];
    }
    function mouseout(e) {
        if (this.id in images)
            this.src = images[this.id][1];
    }
    $("#comicssubsite, #artworksubsite, #aboutsubsite").hover(mouseover, mouseout);
    // You might want to use a loop instead, then you don't need to write the ids twice:
    // for (var id in images)
    //     $('#'+id).hover(mouseover, mouseout);
});
```

Comment: I like this method a lot. Can you explain how I integrate this with the HTML like I have above? I tried using the css, but I don't like how that's working.

Comment: Even though CSS may be the better option here I have to +1 for absolutely beautiful use of jQuery!

Comment: @Growler: It should work right away. Make sure to have the jQuery file included before it, and you can remove those inline-event-handler attributes from your image-tags.

Comment: @PeteUh: Actually, it does not use jQuery everywhere (as claimed above), but only where it is needed for cross-browser consistency. I do not like `$(this).attr()` :-)

Comment: @Bergi Hmm... doesn't seem to be swapping :/

Comment: @Growler: You seem to really need to remove the inline handlers, otherwise the bound ones will not fire. Worksforme on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/LLGqR/)

Comment: @Bergi can I also use jquery to keep the current page/sub site I'm on highlighted (so people know which page they're on)

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Why not using `css`(*oops, background image for an image*)?</strike>

```
#comicssubsite {
   background-image: ...
}

#comicssubsite:hover {
   background-image: ...
}
```

Note that your markup is invalid, IDs must be unique, you should use classes instead of the IDs, you can also change the IDs to `Comics`,   `Artwork` ..  and use `hover` and `attr` methods.

```
$('.pages img').hover(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', function(i, src){
       return src.indexOf('hover')
       ? './images/SiteDesign/'+this.id+'_subsites.png'
       : './images/SiteDesign/'+this.id+'_subsites_hover.png'
    })
})
```

Comment: css seems to be the best option. Thanks!

Comment: @Growler You are welcome, if you want to use css, you should choose another element like a div element.

Answer (score 2):

Your first `if` statement is always returning `true` because each image tag has a source.

If you have this:

```
var comic = document.getElementById("comicssubsite").src;
```

and then this:

```
if (comic) {
//code
}
```

All the if statement is doing is checking that comic *exists*, which it does.